# Parse, change and write back HTML in Elixir

Tags: erlang, html-parsing, elixir, dom-manipulation

I need a library to parse HTML, change some attributes of some elements, then write back result into HTML.

Is there a library for it?

In other languages (like PHP), there are DOM parsers. I found libraries for parsing HTML, but none of them allowed manipulation and generation (or I did not see it?).

Comment: Take a look at Floki https://github.com/philss/floki

Comment: @PawełDawczak It does not support manipulating, or writing, does it? I can't find it in documentations.

Comment: BTW, I have searched `elixir html parser` and looked at all libraries on the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is not a library to parse and manipulate and write HTML.

There is this [Eml](https://github.com/zambal/eml) that can write HTML, and although it has parser, it says it is not a multi-purpose one. I think I will do good for now, but for other usages, one might want to use another parser and Eml together to have a better solution.

PS. I will accept this answer if no one provides a better solution in a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [Floki](https://hex.pm/packages/floki)?

> Floki is a simple HTML parser that enables search for nodes using CSS selectors.

Its parsing capabilities seem decent but not sure about manipulation. It has a [transform](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html#transform/2) method but there are no usage examples.

Comment: (Update 2020) Floki now has a method [traverse_and_update](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html#traverse_and_update/2) that can be used to manipulate the tree. Then the method [raw_html](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html#raw_html/2) can write back the HTML string.